# ng-bootbox: multiple custom modals on same view (same controller)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, bootstrap-modal, bootbox

I'm using [ngBootBox](http://eriktufvesson.github.io/ngbootbox/) to have bootstrap modal dialogs in my angularJS project. but I have an issue when i try two custom dialog with different templates in the same page.

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="view(t)"
                    ng-bootbox-title="<i class='fa fa-eye-opened'></i>Details Ticket"
                    ng-bootbox-custom-dialog
                    ng-bootbox-custom-dialog-template="./templates/modal/view-ticket.html"
                    ng-bootbox-buttons="customDialogButtons"
                    ng-bootbox-options="dialogOptions">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-opened" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        View
                </button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="edit(t)"
                    ng-bootbox-title="<i class='fa fa-tags'></i>Edition Ticket"
                    ng-bootbox-custom-dialog
                    ng-bootbox-custom-dialog-template="./templates/modal/add-ticket.html"
                    ng-bootbox-buttons="customDialogButtons"
                    ng-bootbox-options="dialogOptions">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        Add 
                </button>
```

I have these two buttons, but it seems like the first one's template url gets overridden byu the second one; as a result both the modals opens the same template, that is ./templates/modal/add-ticket.html
when i remove the second button, then the first works as expected.

This is not limited to two modals, id i try adding a lot more they will all resolve to the template url of the last one, and all of them will be displaying the same content when opened.

Comment: I created a small [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HOQAAkHqJY3b3y4bfjTe?p=preview) to test your code and it seems to work fine. Which version are you using? And what code lives in `view` and `edit` functions?

Comment: i tried removing both the  functions view and edit, but nothing changes, i didnt include them, for simplicity...

Comment: thanks to your questionning i found what causes the issue i've updated the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/C7aefztAajm2gtKozJkl?p=preview) with the code to reproduce it.  it is because in the controller, i wrote some code to give me access to the scope

Comment: Posted an answer with a suggestion you might use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different `dialogOptions` objects in the buttons.

```
$scope.viewDialogOptions= {
  scope: $scope
}

$scope.editDialogOptions= {
  scope: $scope
}
```

And in html you can have:

```
// Button 1
ng-bootbox-options="viewDialogOptions"

// Button 2
ng-bootbox-options="editDialogOptions"
```

For example, see in updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y8uV9j54GREHafiL7GFW?p=preview).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes it does help :). Thanks!